# How to avoid having duplicate binary values in R

Tags: r, for-loop, duplicates, simulation, probability

I am currently working on building a simulation that simulates user interactions with fake/authentic FB news posts. As I built simulation using for loop, I've ran into the following problem:

First, I wanted to set my loop such that if a person reacts to a FB post (i.e leave a like, love, wow, haha, sad, angry, or care) he/she would leave only one reaction. For instance, if someone leaves a like, he/she shouldn't be able to leave other reactions like love, wow, etc.

This is the code I used for generating simulation data

```
#Creating empty dataframe 
fake_id<-1:1000
like<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
love<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
wow<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
haha<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
sad<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
angry<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
care<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
comment<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))
shares<-rep(NA,max(fake_id))

fake<-data.frame(fake_id,like,love,wow,haha,sad,angry,care,comment,shares)
```

```
#Probability distribution for user interaction with a given FB post
misinformation_prob<-c(0.090637966,0.015194195,0.023018674,0.013500845,0.001573673,0.017003550,0.002058321,0.003093388,0.001312486)
authentic_prob<-c(0.0275070460,0.0103958123,0.0060707537,0.0034785282,0.0007527044,0.0088240139,0.0020064930,0.0019195168,0.0006860144)
prob.dist<-data.frame(misinformation_prob,authentic_prob)
colnames(prob.dist)<-c("Misinformation","Authentic")
rownames(prob.dist)<-c("Likes","Comments","Shares","Loves","Wows","Hahas","Sads","Angrys","Cares")

prob.dist
```

```
#For loop used to create a simulated data

for(i in fake_id){
  fake$like[i]<-sample(x=c(0,1), size=1,prob=c(1-prob.dist[1,'Misinformation'],prob.dist[1,'Misinformation']))
  fake$comment[i]<-sample(x=c(0,1), size=1,prob=c(1-prob.dist[2,'Misinformation'],prob.dist[2,'Misinformation']))
  fake$shares[i]<-sample(x=c(0,1), size=1,prob=c(1-prob.dist[3,'Misinformation'],prob.dist[3,'Misinformation']))
   if(fake$like[i]==1){
    fake[i,3:8]=0
   }else for(j in 3:8){
     if(is.na(fake[i,j])==TRUE){
       fake[i,j]<-sample(x=c(0,1),size=1,prob=c(1-prob.dist[j+1,'Misinformation'],prob.dist[j+1,'Misinformation']))
     }
     if(fake[i,j]==1){
       fake[i,-j]==0
     }
   }
}
```

I hoped that by writing

```
 if(fake[i,j]==1){
       fake[i,-j]==0
     }
```

I'd be able to avoid having duplicate reactions like certain user liking and loving the post simultaneously. Yet, once I run the simulation, I'd occasionally run into this problem that I wanted to avoid. Any input regarding this problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you community!

Comment: My first thought is that there may be a quicker way to do this than all these for loops. However, the specific problem that you are facing is that you have written `if(fake[i,j]==1){ fake[i,-j]==0}`. I am assuming this is just a typo - you want to do assignment within the curly braces (`=`), not comparison of equality (`==`).

Comment: I am curious about "a quicker way to do this" could you please elaborate on what you mean by it?

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate a little on my comment, you have structured the data pretty nicely so once we clean the row names all of this can be vectorised easily:

```r
rownames(prob.dist) <- c("like", "comment", "shares", "love", "wow", "haha", "sad", "angry", "care")
```

We can then create a function to look up the probabilities for each column in your table:

```r
get_prob <- function(col, dat = prob.dist) {
    prob <- c(
        1 - dat[col, "Misinformation"],
        dat[col, "Misinformation"]
    )
    return(prob)
}
```

Then it's a simple matter of running the simulation for each column. First the three columns can be sampled from the distribution randomly based on the probabilities but not depending on likes:

```r
set.seed(100) # for reproducibility

n <- length(fake_id)
independent_cols <- c("like", "comment", "shares")
cols_depend_on_like <- c("love", "wow", "haha", "sad", "angry", "care")
fake[independent_cols] <- lapply(independent_cols, \(col) {
    sample(x = c(0, 1), size = n, prob = get_prob(col), replace = TRUE)
})
```

Note that we are sampling with replacement - which is essentially what you were doing when you did a rowwise sampling without replacement. Then we can add the columns which depend on likes:

```r
zeroes <- fake$like == 1
fake[cols_depend_on_like] <- lapply(cols_depend_on_like, \(col) {
    values <- sample(0:1, size = n, prob = get_prob(col), replace = TRUE)
    values[zeroes] <- 0
    values
})
```

The output is probabilities in the same range as your original code but much quicker:

```r
sapply(fake, sum)
# fake_id    like    love     wow    haha     sad   angry    care comment  shares
#  500500     100      21       2      19       2       4       1      19      20


# Check that all the columns are zeroes that are supposed to be when like==1
sapply(fake[fake$like == 1, ], sum)
# fake_id    like    love     wow    haha     sad   angry    care comment  shares 
#   51347     100       0       0       0       0       0       0       6       2
```

#### Benchmarking

I wanted to compare the performance for fun but also it will hopefully give you a sense of why it is worth doing this in R. This is the benchmarking code:

```r
num_rows <- c(10, 1e2, 1e3, 1e4)
results <- bench::press(
    rows = num_rows,
    {
        # Creating dataframe
        fake_id <- 1:rows
        like <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        love <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        wow <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        haha <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        sad <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        angry <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        care <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        comment <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))
        shares <- rep(NA, max(fake_id))

        fake <- data.frame(fake_id, like, love, wow, haha, sad, angry, care, comment, shares)

        # Probability distribution for user interaction with a given FB post
        misinformation_prob <- c(0.090637966, 0.015194195, 0.023018674, 0.013500845, 0.001573673, 0.017003550, 0.002058321, 0.003093388, 0.001312486)
        authentic_prob <- c(0.0275070460, 0.0103958123, 0.0060707537, 0.0034785282, 0.0007527044, 0.0088240139, 0.0020064930, 0.0019195168, 0.0006860144)
        prob.dist <- data.frame(misinformation_prob, authentic_prob)
        colnames(prob.dist) <- c("Misinformation", "Authentic")
        rownames(prob.dist) <- c("like", "comment", "shares", "love", "wow", "haha", "sad", "angry", "care")

        bench::mark(
            min_iterations = 10,
            check = FALSE,
            rowwise = {
                set.seed(100) # for reproducibility
                for (i in fake_id) {
                    fake$like[i] <- sample(x = c(0, 1), size = 1, prob = c(1 - prob.dist[1, "Misinformation"], prob.dist[1, "Misinformation"]))
                    fake$comment[i] <- sample(x = c(0, 1), size = 1, prob = c(1 - prob.dist[2, "Misinformation"], prob.dist[2, "Misinformation"]))
                    fake$shares[i] <- sample(x = c(0, 1), size = 1, prob = c(1 - prob.dist[3, "Misinformation"], prob.dist[3, "Misinformation"]))
                    if (fake$like[i] == 1) {
                        fake[i, 3:8] <- 0
                    } else {
                        for (j in 3:8) {
                            if (is.na(fake[i, j]) == TRUE) {
                                fake[i, j] <- sample(x = c(0, 1), size = 1, prob = c(1 - prob.dist[j + 1, "Misinformation"], prob.dist[j + 1, "Misinformation"]))
                            }
                            if (fake[i, j] == 1) {
                                fake[i, -j] <- 0
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            vectorised = {
                set.seed(100) # for reproducibility

                n <- length(fake_id)
                independent_cols <- names(fake)[c(2, 9, 10)]
                cols_depend_on_like <- names(fake)[3:8]
                fake[independent_cols] <- lapply(independent_cols, \(col) {
                    sample(x = c(0, 1), size = n, prob = get_prob(col), replace = TRUE)
                })

                fake[cols_depend_on_like] <- lapply(cols_depend_on_like, \(col) {
                    values <- fake[[col]]
                    zeroes <- fake$like == 1
                    n <- sum(!zeroes)

                    values[zeroes] <- 0
                    values[!zeroes] <- sample(0:1, size = n, prob = get_prob(col), replace = TRUE)
                    values
                })
                
            }
        )
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for putting so much effort into this, I really appreciate you for suggesting a code that is so much more efficient than the dirty code that I created. But I do want to ask why you wrote 'values[zeroes] <- 0' when you created 'fake[cols_depend_on_like].' When I try to run this code it returns an error stating that "object 'zeroes' not found." It's hard for me to fix this error because I don't yet quite understand the purpose behind values[zeroes] <- 0. I'd appreciate it so much if you could inform me with your intention behind this code!

Comment: @BoogieLy sorry I forgot to copy/paste the line `zeroes <- fake$like == 1` before the `lapply()`. I've added it in now. It just sets all the values to 0 in those columns in the row that there are likes.

Comment: Hey @SamR, thank you so much for the immense amount of help you've been providing up to this point. Your contribution will be used for a good purpose, I promise. All the best!

Comment: Hi I know it's been a while since I asked this question, but I think I still have some lingering questions. Your codes work great but I am still not sure about the mechanism behind preventing a dummy variable from appearing simultaneously across the interactions that depend on like. For instance, how exactly your code preventing from having a hypothetical user leaving "haha" and "wow" at the same time?

Comment: It doesn't - it just prevents `like` appearing with any other reaction. All other responses are independent of each other. It is possible to amend it to prevent `haha` and `wow` appearing together. I don't know the facebook rules - are you allowed to have more than one reaction in any case or should users always have at most one reaction?

Comment: You are only allowed to have one reaction per post, which complicates a few things. Do you have any suggestions for achieving this end? In my initial for loop I've set fake[i, -j] as a possible solution although it didn't really do justice.

Comment: Yes I have suggestions but it depends how  to interpret your probabilities. Are they independent proportions of how many posts have this reaction? E.g. if `like` had prob 0.5 and `haha`0.3, in 100 posts you would expect a mean of 50 and 30 respectively? I was interpreting them as dependent - i.e. proportions of reactions which are not likes, rather than of the total.

Comment: I apologize for the late response, I didn't get the notification that you left a reply! I would say those probabilities are independent proportions (as far as we are only concerned with reactions such as "like," "love," "haha," etc.), and your example aligns with my expectations. Having said that, what are your suggestions for this?